# OperationalError & ConnectTimeoutError When running multiple queries in snowflake (From many cloud run instances)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

**My platform running over gcp cloud run. The db we use is snowflake.**

Once a week, we schedule (with Cloud Schedule) a job that practically triggers up to 200 tasks (currently, will probably grow up in the future). All tasks is being added to certain queue.

Each task is practically push post call to a cloud-run instance.

Each cloud run instance is handling one request (see also environment settings), means - one task at a time. Moreover, each cloud run has 2 active sessions to 2 databases in snowflake (one for each). The first session is for "global_db" and the other one is to specific "person_id" db (Notice: There might be 2 active session to the same person_id db from different cloud run instances)

Issues:

1 - When set the tasks queue "Max concurrent dispatches" to 1000, I get 503 ("The request failed because the instance failed the readiness check.")
Issue was probably gcp autoscaling capacities - **SOLVED** by decrease the "Max concurrent dispatches" to reasonable number that gcp can handle with.

2- When set the tasks queue "Max concurrent dispatches" to more than 10,
I get multiple ConnectTimeoutError & OperationalError, with the following messages (I removed the long id's and just put {} for make the message shorter):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (snowflake.connector.errors. ) 250003: Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*****.us-central1.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id={REQUEST_ID}&databaseName={DB_NAME}&warehouse={NAME}&request_guid={GUID} (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x3e583ff91550>, 'Connection to *****.us-central1.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

```
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*****.us-central1.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id={ID}&databaseName={NAME}&warehouse={NAME}&request_guid={GUID}(Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x3eab877b3ed0>, 'Connection to *****.us-central1.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

Any ideas how can I solve it?
Ask any Q you have, and I will elaborate

**environment settings -**

- cloud tasks queue - Check multiple configurations for "Max concurrent dispatches", from 10 to 1000 concurrency. max attempts is 1, max dispatches is 500.
- cloud run - 5 hot instances, 1 request per one. Can autoscaling to max 1000 instances.
- snowflake - ACCOUNT parameters were default (MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=8 and STATEMENT_QUEUED_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS=0) and was changed to (in order to handle those errors):

  - MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL - 32
  - STATEMENT_QUEUED_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS - 600

Comment: Does it works well if "Max concurrent dispatches" is less than 10 ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with 5 and it's worked fine

Comment: The error suggests that your login request is timing out, so you don't even reach the stage of a running a query. As it works for less than 10, I am thinking about some restrictions/concurrency from the Cloud side.

Comment: Do you mean gcp OR snowflake?

Comment: I would think GCP, but it's hard to say. On Snowflake side you're not even reaching to use the MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL as you're still at login request, so it's not a concurrency issue from Snowflake from my point of view. On the other hand I would not touch MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL. When you reach MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL queries are queued, not dropped, so that parameter is not the cause here for sure.

Comment: It seems that the error depends on the warehouse cluster amount & size.

Answer (score 1):

I want to inform that we've found the problem - When the project was in it's beginning, we've created a VPC with static IP to the cloud run instance.

Unfortunately, the maximum number of connections to a single VPC network is 25..